# why doesn't String.contains() return true in this case?

Tags: java

```
System.out.println(ganzeZeile[26]);
System.out.println(filter.get(11));
System.out.println(ganzeZeile[26].contains(filter.get(11)));
```

`ganzeZeile` is an array of Strings. 
`filter` is an ArrayList of Strings.

```
ganzeZeile[26] = "Ich gebe der Dozentin/dem Dozenten die Gesamtnote."
filter.get(11) = "dem Dozenten die Gesamtnote"
```

But `ganzeZeile[26].contains(filter.get(11))` returns `false`.

Isn't `"dem Dozenten die Gesamtnote"` part of `"Ich gebe der Dozentin/dem Dozenten die Gesamtnote."`, and therefore `contains(...)` should return `true`?

edit:

i've got my code and the testcode from assylias in a testclass, both return different values(!). i dont see any difference in code tbh.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class test1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] ganzeZeile = new String[28];
    ArrayList<String> filter = new ArrayList<String>();

    ganzeZeile[26] = "Ich gebe der Dozentin/dem Dozenten die Gesamtnote.";
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        filter.add("");
    }
    filter.add("dem Dozenten die Gesamtnote");

    System.out.println(ganzeZeile[26]);
    System.out.println(filter.get(11));
    System.out.println(ganzeZeile[26].contains(filter.get(11)));//returns false
}

//  public static void main(String[] args) {
//      String[] ganzeZeile = new String[28];
//      ArrayList<String> filter = new ArrayList<String>();
//
//      ganzeZeile[26] = "Ich gebe der Dozentin/dem Dozenten die Gesamtnote.";
//      for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
//          filter.add("");
//      }
//      filter.add("dem Dozenten die Gesamtnote");
//
//      System.out.println(ganzeZeile[26]);
//      System.out.println(filter.get(11));
//      System.out.println(ganzeZeile[26].contains(filter.get(11))); //prints true
//  }
}
```

since i use the newest javaversion (1.7 atm) it could be the reason this code behaves so different.

regards

Comment: Do you mean that ganzeZeile is a String[] and filter is an ArrayList<String>?  It might help to show us the declarations for those variables.

Comment: Can't reproduce, working fine for me.

Comment: Have you verified with the debugger or logging that 26 and 11 truly contain what you expected?

Comment: @AHungerArtist yes i did go through with the debugger. will check twice if i find something suspicious. thx

Comment: either `filter.get(11)` returns different values on first and second call or you have a slight difference in those strings. Like an additional whitespace at the end of your filter string.

Comment: even if. i check them at the end of the program and syso confirms that they are strings. really awkward behavior. the possibilities of some escape sequence is given because the first string contains /. gonna check that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't reproduce the behavior based on the information you gave - the problem is probably somewhere else:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    String[] ganzeZeile = new String[27];
    List<String> filter = new ArrayList<String>();

    ganzeZeile[26] = "Ich gebe der Dozentin/dem Dozenten die Gesamtnote.";
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        filter.add("");
    }
    filter.add("dem Dozenten die Gesamtnote");

    System.out.println(ganzeZeile[26]);
    System.out.println(filter.get(11));
    System.out.println(ganzeZeile[26].contains(filter.get(11))); //prints true
}
```

Comment: hmm interesting! should have tested the code in clean environment myself (didnt thought that my code would be the cause of a simple string compare).

Comment: i tested your code and it printed true as stated. i rewrote the code without any changes whatsoever and i get false. wtf is wrong with my eclipse Oo...